# Выполнить тоже самое только проще

Tags: javascript

```
(n = eCr('canvas', {'width':(w = this.v.videoWidth), 'height': (h = this.v.videoHeight)})).getContext('2d').drawImage(this.v, 0, 0, w, h);
this.img.src = n.toDataURL();
```

Работает, создаем холст с заданными размерами, затем выхватываем кадр. В итоге получаем изображение с соотношением сторон тоже что и у кадра.

А затем в тег img, вставляем строчку.

Вопрос в том, возможно ли проще выполнить тоже самое. Столько кода, размеров, 2 раза создаем объект. canvas и img

Что подсказывает, что тоже самое возможно выполнить проще...

Comment: У вас 2 строчки... куда уже проще?

Comment: Не понимаю, для чего создавать canvas с указанием размеров. Разве невозможно через new image, не указывая размеров. Просто взять кадр и получить на выходе изображение с исходными размерами кадра?

Comment: что ты имеешь ввиду под _взять кадр_? нет смысла делать `w = this.v.videoWidth` и для высоты - ты можешь использовать одни и те же значения

Comment: @Aleks не думаю что такое возможно, да и смысл такое делать в вендорных методах? Тогда почему бы уже сразу не внедрить методы / функции для создания игр? Тот же бред получается.